# is chair not recognizing me on purpose or am I selfish and can't see reality?

Tags: phd

My chair never says publicly good things about me, but he does about others. I am also an expert in one area, and this person does not acknowledge my input. He has meetings only with me and then with other people, but never together. I feels there is always something behind the back.
Everything this person does has an agenda, and I have seen it in action: you talk about one thing and the sharing of information is always modified.
I am the only one he targets, ignores mostly. No other faculty, just me.
What should I do?

Comment: This seems more like a question best suited to https://workplace.stackexchange.com or even https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is appreciation for others work expressed publicly or it happens between you and the chair? Besides, this kind of questions can not be really answered. Sometimes chairs are right, too (surely it is not your case... You see where the point is?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initiate, in my experience.

Specifically, try to first demonstrate some genuine compassion towards your Chair, e.g. reach out and extend some empathy toward him / her about the situation.

I would be inquisitive, rather than be quietly hostile.  Can you ask him / her some open-ended questions to formulate a clearer understanding about things?  If so, and this is productive, then try to listen carefully to understand, without rushing or even intending to respond.

Speak to him / her respectfully about it, and good luck.  Do not be adversarial.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is absolutely great. What do you mean by not being adversarial? Thank you so much again, this helps a LOT

Comment: https://hunch.net/?p=499

Comment: The hunch article is a good one @MonkeyButter, I just read it.

Comment: @MonkeyButter adversarial would be "you never give me any positive feedback, why are you so mean to me?" Non-adversarial would be "I feel that I could be of more value to our team if you would be more vocal about when you feel I'm doing a good job; would you be willing to do so?". These are of course just example sentences that may miss the exact mark: the core concept is that adversarial frames the situation as a battle where the chair and you are on opposite sides, and non-adversarial puts the chair and you on the same side. The latter is likely to be more productive.

Comment: Thank you so so so much. This is amazing feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much to all